# iOS Grid View with support for different sized cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gridview

I'm an iOS developer looking for a solution to a tricky problem. 
I need to create a grid view/ mosaic view to layout cells of **different** sizes (both width and height).

I basically need the functionality of a GMGridView, with horizontal scrolling/paging, the ability to edit, and drag cells to new locations, thus rearranging the entire grid view. I've looked at all of the current open source grid views out there, and found none with variable sized cells.

One solution I have thought about is 2 tableviews both rotated for the horizontal scrolling, and then intercept some UITableView scrolling methods, to then scroll the other tableview together. This is not ideal, as I will be unable to move a cell from one view to another, and I'm not sure how happy apple will be about it.

I also know of some possible (confidential?) support for this coming in the next version of iOS, but would like to keep my app supporting previous versions of iOS.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

[image: http://bigreddog.com.au/files/pedals/grid_view_screenshot.png]

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is kind of old, but here is a list of relevant projects: *https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicUI
*https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Consider adding more information into the answer

Answer (score 0):

GridViews on iOS are a pain. Fortunately Apple is coming up with `UICollectionViews` that are optimized to build grids. This is coming in iOS6 and it's still under NDA so check out the documentation on Apple's website for more information.

The question you need to solve now is whether you want iOS5 retro-compatibility or not